# Angular 2 Typescript - Enable CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’

Tags: angular, typescript, cors

I have Angular 2 typescript application running on my localhost. I have to access external REST API in my application. Whenever I try to access, I get this error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at ***. (Reason: CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

What is the best solution to fix this issue. I dont want to use any plugin/addOns.
I dont think so this package would work for Angular 2 Typescript application.It is used for express.js

```
npm install cors --save
```

How do I set this  CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ using typescript for entire project/application? Where do I need to add this header in below code?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   let myurl='http://remoteIP/api';
request.open('GET', myurl, true);
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        console.log('DataURL:', reader.result);
    };
};
request.send();
```

Comment: This header needs to be added on the server side, not in client-side TypeScript code.

Comment: @RayToal How do I add it on the server side?

Comment: That depends on the server technology you are using. The way you worded the question it sounded like you were accessing someone else's external REST API which you would have no control over. If you are writing the server yourself, you can add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the responses that need it (i.e., the ones access through Ajax calls).

Comment: @RayToal The server is Jenkins Server. I am trying to access Jenkins Rest API for e.g. `http://ci.jruby.org/job/jruby-base/lastSuccessfulBuild/` in my angular typescript application. Angular application is on my localhost. This is when I get the CORS issue.

Comment: [This Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin) might help you then

Answer (score 2):

*The server that hosts that API* needs to enable CORS. This is a limitation of client-side languages - they make these REST requests through the browser. The browser will change whatever mocked origin headers you give it to your actual website's headers.

This isn't an issue with server-side languages, such as PHP or even nodeJS/expressJS.

Comment: If at all I have access to the server , How do I enable CORS on that server ?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors - this is for node.js/express.js...I have to run this script on server side?

Comment: No, first see what kind of server you're running. If it's Apache, search this website for "CORS apache". If it's nginx, search this website for "CORS nginx", etc.

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans It is a ubuntu server, where Jenkins is running. I am trying to access Jenkins Rest API in my angular application.

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans Thanks a lot. It helped to resolve the issue. I installed CORS plugin.